# Errors when I put buttons very close to each other in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, button, location

In Mainstoryboard (I'm not sure if this also applies to earlier versions) I want to put two buttons very close to each other with one or two pixels separating them. Mainstoryboard allows this, but when I run it on the simulator, it puts one button partially on top of the other, even though they're supposed to be separated. I think this might have to do with the white border that appears around a button when you double-click it, but I can't find any way to change this border. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: show some screen shots or the code if u set the frame for buttons in code\

Comment: I don't set the frame or positions for the buttons in the code. I just put the buttons on the viewcontroller in mainstoryboard, and this happens even when the buttons aren't hooked up to outlets from the code.

Comment: could you post the screenshots of both simulator and canvas??

Comment: No idea why, but the problem seems to have fixed itself. The buttons weren't appearing where I put them before, now they are. Hope it was a glitch and it doesn't occur again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was caused by the fact that I was using the iPhone 4 simulator with a mainstoryboard that was supposed to go with the iPhone 5. So it was cramming the buttons together and changing locations to fit them onto the smaller screen. I fixed it permanently by changing my simulator to the 4 inch retina display.